# Why is ${env:VARNAME} in my VS Code .env file not being expanded (on Windows 10)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have defined a system environment variable:

```
HOME=d:
```

In my VS CODE .env file, I define a new variable:

```
pythonpath=${env:HOME}\foo
```

When I debug my app and check os.getenv("pythonpath"), it has value

```
${env:HOME}\foo
```

but I expected HOME variable to be expanded with the resulting string

```
d:\foo
```

My source of info on this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file